# How to debug TypeScript compilation performance issues

Tags: typescript, performance, compilation, profiling

My TypeScript project has been going for a while now, and is quite large. Recently compile time performance has become significantly worse. I think it's likely that some of the 'neat' typing tricks that I've included somewhere are causing this.

Unfortunately it's a large project, and includes many other large TypeScript dependencies, so it's hard to know the exact root cause.

Are there any tools to debug TS compiler typechecking performance in situations like this? E.g. to see which files/types take TypeScript the most time to compile.

Comment: Does `--diagnostics` help at all?

Comment: @AaronBeall `--diagnostics` tells me how many types & files I have, among other things. That doesn't get me any closer to knowing which files or types are causing problems though. Is there a way to know, for example, which files have generated the most types? Most 'expensive' types would be most interesting, but I suspect hard to define.

Comment: I, too, am interested in diagnosing sluggish TypeScript performance - any clues from the community?

Comment: I have a 1600 loc project using the typebox library https://github.com/sinclairzx81/typebox and I'm running into performance issues as well (120+ seconds to compile).

Comment: You could try [this approach](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35729#issuecomment-582198756) and inspect the size of each declaration file to see which ones are the biggest: `tsc --noEmit false --declaration --emitDeclarationOnly --extendedDiagnostics --declarationDir ./declarations`

Answer (score 6):

TypeScript 4.1 introduced a generateTrace flag to make it easier to identify the parts of a program that are taking the most time to compile.

There is a dedicated WIKI [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance-Tracing)

Please keep in mind:

> This feature is still experimental and will likely change significantly in TS 4.2